Vue Generic Components 'T' is not defined
Simple question, I've updated to  Vue 3.4.30, and am trying to use Generic components, but when trying to use T as a type for a property, I am getting this error..  Any suggestions would be welcome.
Was using an older version of vue, haven't updated any other packages (as seen in the package.json copy/paste)...
"vue": "^3.2.37"


            "dependencies": {
        "@codemirror/lang-json": "^6.0.1",
        "@codemirror/lint": "^6.4.2",
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.17.0",
        "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.7",
        "@types/node": "^18.1.8",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "codemirror": "^6.0.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
        "inversify": "^6.0.1",
        "linq-collections": "^1.0.254",
        "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
        "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
        "lodash.merge": "^4.5.0",
        "mitt": "^3.0.1",
        "pinia": "^2.1.7",
        "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
        "powerbi-client": "^2.22.3",
        "quasar": "^2.13.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "sortablejs": "^1.15.1",
        "vite": "^4.5.0",
        "vite-plugin-commonjs": "^0.7.1",
        "vite-plugin-require": "^1.1.11",

        "vue": "^3.4.30",

        "vue-codemirror": "^6.1.1",
        "vue-draggable-plus": "^0.3.2",
        "vue-gtag-next": "^1.14.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
        "vue3-openlayers": "^0.1.75"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
        "@types/pluralize": "^0.0.33",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.37",
        "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "2.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.51.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
        "sass": "^1.69.4",
        "style-resources-loader": "^1.5.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "vue-loader-v16": "^16.0.0-beta.5.4"
    }
}

Tried:
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">

<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends ChildEntryModel">


Update:
const props = defineProps<{ modelValue: T }>();
still doesn't work.

This should not work, as you declare your props using the default defineProps({...}) macro, that uses actual javascript values for the prop definitions.
As T is just a type, and does not result in an actual javascript object, it is not defined during the runtime of defineProps.
As stated in https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html, you can use pure type annotations to define your component props:
defineProps<{ modelValue: T}>()

You can use the generic type parameter T like so in a component:
Vue SFC Playground example

This is exactly what the documentation shows as an example? Am I missing something here?
https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components

Ahh i see what you mean. I updated to hav ethe correct prop definition but.. still the same issue.
